# iPhone SDK: To the iPhone/iPod touch?

Tags: iphone

I have SDK 3.1 for iPhone.

I have made an application, and i want this to put on my iPod Touch.

How to? Is there a need of paying to Apple for a paid developer account? Or is there a way to NOT pay...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop and test on the simulator without a paid account (you still need to sign up for the free developer account) but in order to install to an iPhone/iPod Touch legitimately you will need to pay the yearly developer fee and setup the device provisioning and all that fun stuff :)  It may take a couple days to go through so if there is a deadline looming it's best to get this out of the way.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a jailbroken phone, I believe the only way to get apps on your phone is to pay for the developer account.

Comment: i do have a jailbroken device, and i have Installous... I tried to build it, copy it trough openSSH and installed it... Trying to open, but crashes. I did not edit the info.plist, so that could be the problem. Tried even to sync it with iTunes, but said that 'it does not have a signature...'