# self sign my code and test on iphone in xCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, provisioning, codesign

I have created iphone project. I want to test it on my iphone. I don't have an account on itunesconnect so I'm unable to load a certificate to sign my code.
I've created my own certificate (Keychain Access->Certificate Assistant ->Create Certificate).
But I could not sign my project with it. xCode can not see my self-signed certificate.

How can I sign my code to test it on my device without itunesconnect account?

Comment: You have to join the iOS Developer Program (I think that's what you mean by iTunesConnec-account). It's not possible without that (except for jail-broken devices). You don't only need a certificate, but also a provisioning profile, which you get only as member of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A certificate is not a provisioning profile. You need a provisioning profile for the device in question to load onto it. For this, you need to be a registered iOS developer, which is $99 per year.

Answer (score 3):

Without jailbreak you can not.

Comment: Confusing answer. And it does work on a non-jailbroken phone. (hurr-durr)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to run an app on a device without a valid developer account and all that goes with it. Not legitimately anyway (I know nothing about jailbreaking.)

Answer (score 2):

Besides @Almo 's answer6  You may test your application on jailbroken iPhone.
There is at least one working solution:
http://www.gumballtech.com/2010/04/14/on-device-testing-wout-paying-99/

..Then simply send file to device via SSH.

There's also other solutions but i don't know if it working (for example [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak) )

Comment: I worked like this (i.e. with jailbroken iPhone) one year ago, with XCode 3.x and iPhoneOS 3.x. I'm going to extend my answer with links to solutions. it s only a little inconvenient cause you have no debugger (but you still have logs) and every time you need  to transfer your app through SSH manually.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested my applications on a jailbroken device, it does indeed work.
Also, >> @Almo