# Resume safari from suspended state iOS

Tags: ios, url, browser, safari, url-scheme

My question pertains to integrating a web app with a native app. A button in the web app opens  up my native app, and then in my native app I want a "return" button. I wanted the "return" button to just resume safari from it's suspended state, but it seems like the only way to communicate with Safari is to open an http URL.

Opening an http URL will tell Safari to navigate to a specific page, but I *don't* want to alter the page which the user left off on, so I don't think this approach will work for me. Is it possible to just "Resume" safari from its suspended state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible without jailbreaking the device.

This SO post seems to answer your question:

[Open Mobile Safari without using openURL:url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170668/open-mobile-safari-without-using-openurlurl)

Comment: Thank you, hopefully someone will revisit this someday if it ever becomes possible