# iOS 9 and launchApplicationWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I have been reading up about launchApplicationWithIdentifier because I want to bring an application from the background in to foreground.  Most posts about this are very old and so I wanted to ask a couple of questions.

I am aware this is a private API, this is for a test only not a production app

Does launchApplicationWithIdentifier still work iOS9?

Does the device have to be jailbroken?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11047952/5060335)

Comment: Yes it was from 2012, entitlements are not the same now