# Xcode 4.3.2 bypass code signing

Tags: ios, code-signing, xcode4.3

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 to compile Cydia Applications.

4.1 has a simple way to allow un-signed Applications to build (plist edit), however, in 4.3.2, it does not share the same simplicity of editing a plist file.

Now, in 4.3.2, I receive this error:

`CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.1'`

So my question is, how Do I bypass code signing in Xcode 4.3.2?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS5.1'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899920/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios5-1)

Comment: not exactly, that asker is needs to get a valid code sign for his application to submit it in the app store while this asker wants to avoid codesigning altogether to submit in cydia heres how you would do it in xcode 4: http://txcom2003.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/disable-code-signing-in-xcode-4/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found it! the plist is located at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/SDKSettings.plist
```

i assume its the same steps as http://txcom2003.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/disable-code-signing-in-xcode-4/   have not tested it yet.

EDIT: Tested it, and it worked. :)

Comment: Your link is not available now, but I found another answer: set CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED to NO.

Comment: I did what iwill suggested (using xcodebuild command line setting and/or adding a custom property in the IDE) for an Xcode 5 project. That project builds a MacOS subproject of an iOS main project. This combination caused the MacOS project to fail during "Check dependencies" because CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED was set to YES in the inherited environment. Not as intrusive as this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The post below allowed me to compile from command line without changing my xcode settings (in case you still want to be able to easily test, debug on your phone and build for the app store)

[Building iOS applications using xcodebuild without codesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034133/building-ios-applications-using-xcodebuild-without-codesign)

1. cd to your xcode project directory
2. do this: `xcodebuild clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO`

You will get the application built in the release folder unless you pass the output folder as a param.

In order to locate the output, do the following:
XCode > Preferences > Locations
Below derived data is the folder to which xcode outputs the apps. I use a list view to check the time of change, which allows me to locate the correct app.

Of course, you'll next have to sign the app with ldid and do other stuff required for Cydia, the big boss does a great job there:
http://thebigboss.org/hosting-repository-cydia/submit-your-app/compile-for-cydia-submission