# Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS5.1'

Tags: code-signing, xcode4.3, ipa, ios5

I am using xCode 4.3.1. After i created a project, i build it and tried to Archive. Then i got an error saying; (This is my first project in xCode 4.3.1)

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type
>   'Application' in SDK 'iOS5.1'

What does this mean ? and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It means you haven't assigned a provisioning profile to the configuration.

Usually it's because "Any iOS SDK" must have a profile and cannot be set to "Don't sign".

All this and more is answered in the [TN2250 Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html) about Code Signing and Troubleshooting.

Comment: Changed my target's Provisioning profile from Automatic to which actual provisioning profile it should use fixed my problem in XCode 6.4.

Comment: That technote link does not work anymore. Anyone knows the new link?

Comment: This might help "Technical Q&A QA1814
Setting up Xcode to automatically manage your provisioning profiles" https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/qa/qa1814/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014030

Comment: @JD link now fixed

Answer (score 28):

One possible solution which works for me:

1. Search "code sign" in Build settings
2. Change everything in code signing identity to "iOS developer", which are "Don't code sign" originally.

Bravo!

Comment: but you need to buy developer license to be able to compile with iOS developer...

Comment: @DainiusKreivys No need to buy one anymore. You can use your own free developer account to deploy your code to iOS devices. Buying one is only necessary to submit to App Store.

Comment: @Muhsin Zahid Ugur   since when?

Comment: @DainiusKreivys Since June 8th, 2015. "You can launch your app on a device using a free Apple ID account". See the second paragraph : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW3

Answer (score 4):

This error was caused, for me, by different circumstances. A downloaded project tutorial had a default setting of [Project]>Targets>Build Settings>Architectures>Build Active Architecture Only>Release = "Yes." I wasn't intending to build a release, so the solution was to set Release (which presumably requires not just a developer profile but distribution profile) to "No."

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this by using the simulator if you don't actually need to be deploying to a device.  That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem even though I had a valid provisioning profile for the device. It turned out that I had changed my developer account password and needed to update the password in xcode. This is done by going to preferences-Accounts-Apple ID and entering the new password.

Comment: Note that setting the Team under Identity simply told me that my profile did not allow ios development. It would have been helpful if it had a clue about the password for the account not working.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Xcode did the trick for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The other issue here lies under Code Signing Identity under the Build Settings.  Be sure that it contains the Code Signing Identity: "iOS Developer" as opposed to "Don't Code Sign."  This will allow you to deploy it to your iOS device. Especially, if you have downloaded a GitHub example or something to this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with an Apple Sample Code. In project "PhotoPicker", in Architectures, the base SDK was:

[image: screen shot 1]

This parametrization provokes the message:

**CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'**

It assumes you have a developer user, so... use it and change:

[image: screen shot 2]

And the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

TN2250 Tech  document was retired,To resolve this add IOs5.1 or 8.1 sdk field under Anyios SDK field

in code sign problem will solved

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem because option `In-App Purchase` was `ON` in project's `Capabilities`. If your app is not need in-app purchases - turn it off, or you need to set a correct provision profile to `Debug` scheme.