# iphone code sign error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, sign

phone version is 6.1.2 , Xcode sdk version is 6.1 . Command + R run app in simulator , it works well, but Command + R run app in my phone , xcode shows error as below:

**CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.1'**

i do not know why , how can i fix this problem.

Comment: you have to add your certificate to run on device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS5.1'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899920/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios5-1)

Answer (score 0):

From Apple [Technical Note TN2250](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html):

```
[BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.0'
```

> Use the steps in section Assigning Provisioning Profiles to Build Configurations to correct your Code Signing Identities configuration and match the steps and figures closely. Specifically, the line reading "Any iOS SDK" must have a provisioning profile assigned to it and cannot be set to "Don't Code Sign".

Comment: Build setting --> Code signing --> Code signing identify --> Debug , Set Code sign with your certification . it works well .