# code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.0'

Tags: ios, certificate

I 'v finished my app, i created the dev & distribution profile   , and I 'v tested it without codesign and it's run o.k , but when I changed the codesign to distribution profile I get this error    Check dependencies

```
    CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.0'
```

my device is 6.0.1, my xcode is 4.5.2
   any help please

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899920/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios5-1

Answer (score 4):

You need to go to your build setting and set a "Code Signing Identity" for each debug and release for "Any iOS SDK".

Answer (score 1):

@mskw is correct, but there's something else I had to do to get it working (small and subtle but necessary!):

Click the small button at the top of the code window, showing an iOS device (which I happened to have plugged in):

[image]

And instead choose a simulator.

[image]

I think this was just because I happened to have my iPad plugged in at the time. :)

Answer (score 1):

1.Uncheck the test in the Edit Scheme.

2.i changed ios developer into 'Any iOS SDK'in Code signing identity but not worked.

**Finally**

i Changed the 'Any iOS SDK' to iOS Developer in the debug & Release in Code signing identity like this picture

[image]