# Install iOS app on single device without developer programme

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there anno 2019 a way to install an iOS app I developed (in Xcode) on my own iPhone without having to register in the developer programme, which I don't want to because it costs money and at this point I'm just trying stuff out. I have no intention of installing it on any devices but my own.

I looked [here](https://codeburst.io/latest-itunes-12-7-removed-the-apps-option-how-to-install-ipa-on-the-device-3c7d4a2bc788) and tried [ad-hoc archives/builds](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev7ccaf4d3c) but these require signing the app, which itself leads to registration and payment for the developer programme. At least I am unable to add devices to the developer account without first paying.

There are also [older questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494398/install-ios-apps-on-device-without-developer-program-ios-5-1) on SO but they all deal with old versions of Xcode or iTunes, which does not support installing apps anymore. I suppose Apple regularly make it harder to avoid the developer program, which is why many instructions are outdated.

I did try the following:

- Build for profiling
- Show 'Products/*.app' in folder
- Create Payload directory and copy app into that
- Compress and rename extension from zip to ipa
- Drag-and-drop ipa onto iPhone with Apple Configurator 2 (connected with cable)

For some reason the app is greyed out on the Home screen, but I cannot open it at all.

Comment: you can always test your app on simulator.

Comment: Yes, but I am fiddling with Core Motion, which is not supported in the Simulator. So I'd like to see it on a real device.

Comment: That's a separate concern. My question is about installing an app on a single device. I might use an approach as described [here](https://www.marisibrothers.com/2016/02/simulating-signals-in-swift-part-2.html).

Comment: No. You have to pay to apple.

Comment: Yes, just sign in with your apple account. They have limitation like no more than 2 apps and it will work only for a week.
Or you can try Cydia Impactor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can using your regular Apple account. But there is some limitations like you can't install more than 2 apps and apps will expire in 1 week.

[image]