# Can't run my iOS app on my ipod touch

Tags: iphone, ios5, jailbreak, ipod-touch, ios5.1

I have an app that I built using iOS 5.1 compatibility.

I haven't been able to follow paths like building it using archiving - I have been using a remote mac and some issues keep restricting me from doing that.

So I prepared an .ipa file by doing this:
- Payload folder
- copy myapp.app package to Payload
- Zipped Payload

Now I got this Payload onto my itunes on another pc (because the mac is remote so no way to get onto ipod touch from there)

My ipod touch shows iOS version 4.2.1 which it says latest. No further upgrade available.
The model is mb528zp. The free space on ipod is 700 MB, which is more than what's needed.

I can see myapp under itunes library app section.

When I try syncing myapp from under the device->apps, it does seem to sync up - but at the end it is not synced.

What do I do?

Comment: Your way of using a remote mac is going to be a huge bottleneck - get access to a locally connectable mac.

Comment: @Till, I know. But I had exhausted all other options. I didn't have much budget. Besides, as I read later, its not that hard to transfer the ipa to my local host, but getting it to work on ipod 2g seems to be real bottleneck. I am observing that some apps just sync well, but many others don't.

Comment: @TheDeveloper, yes, I used XCode 4.3 - and built the project using iOS 5.1. Is there any option to build it using older iOS versions? I think my app is pretty simple and won't require iOS latest version for that matter.

Comment: Try doing this (You will **need** a Distribution Certificate)     Change Target to iOS Device > Go to Product > then Archive > then in the new window click distribute > Ad-Hoc > Choose your Ad-Hoc Certificate then click Next > Save the file to your desktop > Drag into iTunes > Sync!

Comment: @TheDeveloper, which target are you talking about? 1) The one available in schemes, with iPhone simulator <version no> OR 2) The one available in Project settings->info tab->iOS Deployment Target? When I tried setting 1), it results in lot of compilation issues (I mentioned in my below comments too). When I tried setting 2), syncing still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, option 1) doesn't give me compilation issues. It gives me single error called "CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.1'". I know of a method to bypass this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898039/xcode-4-3-2-bypass-code-signing, but I do not admin rights on this remote mac. I am trying hard to approach admins but weekend is preventing it. Anyway, was of the idea maybe some other workaround can help meanwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your deployment target is set to the wrong iOS version. Try setting your project iOS Deployment Target to 4.2 or below and it should work (click the project in the Project Navigator, then click the name of your project, not the target, and you should see the Info tab selected with the option there)

Comment: Thanks, but this results in lot of compilation errors. Like I didn't declare some method, 'weak' property cannot be synthasized and so on. Do you think I should make it backward compatible?

Comment: OK, I compiled it well using the deployment target you said. I made it 4.2. But still the app doesn't sync onto my ipod having 4.2.1. (One more thing that wonders me is the target device selected in the scheme on the toolbar. Currently, its iPhone simulator 5.1, and not 4.2. If I make it 4.2, I get lot of compilation issues - The ones I mentioned in prior comment. Do you think it is inevitable. Should I rework it to make it backward compatible? I can think of it but for now I really really want some quick testing on my device.

Comment: Your target device (if you're building for a device) should be set to "iOS device", not the simulator. You will probably also have to do as TheDeveloper says and build it Ad-Hoc to get it syncing on to the device if you're not going to connect the device to XCode and build it that way. To make the AdHoc easier consider using https://testflightapp.com/

Comment: So far I disabled code signing in XCode package. But I can't seem to go further after creating an archive as Ad-hoc distribution requires identity, which I don't seem to have. [I have a free apple ID which I supplied to 'choose identity screen' but it failed]. So how do I go about it? Can someone list the steps involved? I read many conflicting tutorials online and also see things fail despite everything followed. Very greatful for the help!

Comment: Basically I am looking for ways to test out my .app package on my iPhone before signing up for apple developer program. Firstly I bypassed code signing. Because of that, I cannot go testinflight.com path. I have read that creating ipa will work. I tried creating it using debug, release versions build, targeted for 4.2 OS. Yet, itunes won't sync my app to my ipod touch 2g (having 4.2.1 iOS). I have itunes 10.

Comment: You can't run it on your iOS device without signing up to the Apple Developer Program (there's probably a way if the device is jailbroken but I've never looked in to it).

Comment: Thanks @Workshed, can you point me to some reliable list of instructions for doing it step-by-step? Not to mention I already have a free developer account.

Comment: As in step by step instructions for getting it running on a jailbroken device or step by step instructions for signing up to the Apple Developer Program? In both cases I'm sure you could find it with a quick Google.

Comment: I just went ahead enrolling for apple developer program for $99. And what I found? Its not available in my country! It told me to print and fax some stupid form to apple. I am reading other people like me, they respond to such forms at least a month later! (if someone have any better idea, tell me, I am pulling my hair!)  If it really takes that long, I have no way but to jailbreak it to get things going till they wake up. Someone, please help....

Comment: Can you not just apply for the program and continue to use the simulator for development until your application is approved? P.S. You're likely to get more answers in future if you approve some of the answers to your questions on here - I see you have several questions open and you've not accepted any answers.

Comment: My app is already at the level beyond simulator testing, that's why I am freaked out. I am anyway faxing it up, will have to wait till it comes back. About the questions I asked, most of them got comments, not answers, which I already responded to. As for the answers, I cannot rep them up as I don't have 15 reputation mark myself.