# Can I test my apps on my device for free? iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Yesterday I installed Xcode 4.3.2 and I want to test my app on my iPod touch ;) What should I do to test my app on my iPod for free? ( I can't pay 99$ ). I have a jailbroken iPod.

[Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

This way doesn't work :(
The application turns on and off after a while :(

Please, help me!

Comment: You linked a duplicate question in your question. It has been answered. It is not possible.

Comment: I know that it is possible ^^ My classmate did it a few days ago but I  can't contact him.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried, but doing a google search, [Jailcoder](http://jailcoder.com/) looks like a solution if you have a jailbroken iPod. Anyway, you will need your apple developer program to distribute your application. Good luck! Oh, and if you try this, let us know how it worked!

Comment: I know that I will need to pay to distribute my apps ;) In this time I want to only test my apps ;)