# Do I need to enroll in iOS developer program to distribute my application?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos

I want to export my simple application in xcode 4.33
But I failed to do that because of missing code signing.
I read the following instruction and tried to get a iOS certificates.
The xCode told me that I am not in one of the development team.

[instruction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/CodeSigning/CodeSigning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH7-SW1)

I am an individual developer.
So I have to enroll in the iOS development program and pay $99/year
to export my application??

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure you will need to do that, so that you can have your own Certificate and keys

Comment: thx, you are the first one.
btw is there any limitation on the number of device that my application can install on??

Comment: if you want to distribute your application to devices, and not to the store, you can choose enterprise program (no limit) https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: if you choose normal program you can only distribute to 200 devices

Comment: My application is developed for a project in school.
I need to  distribute my applcation to iphone/ipod for testing.
Which program should i join??
University or normal program??

Comment: um..may be a few only.
I just need to distribute the apps to the phone/ipod of me or my member for testing.And do demonstration of the application to lecturer.

Comment: Then go with the university one, its free https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/university/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you indeed need to sign up as a registered developer to distribute your app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to do that to purchase your app to Apple store.