# How to gain root access to Xcode to Disable Code Signing

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I am trying to push an app to a jailbroken iPhone for development testing. I want to follow the steps in the second answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak), which involves editing Xcode's SDKSettings plist:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/SDKSettings.plist

When I try to edit this file, I get an error that I'm not the owner and cannot unlock it. How do I get root privileges for this file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo chmod 777 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/SDKSettings.plist
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I also had to change the permissions for the containing folder for this to work: `sudo chmod 777 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk`

Comment: its not working for me. so simple copy the file somewhere.Then edit that file and delete old after paste new file with same name. its working fine for me.