# Controlling iOS device

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Is it possible from my app to run in background, turn on/off other apps, control the iOS device without jailbreaking it? I understand that this app *will not pass* Apple's review/approval, but I am not planning it, instead, I just need to distribute it to clearly defined list of devices. I just prefer not to require to jailbreak device.. Is it possible?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "control the iOS device"? which aspects do you want to control exactly? there are private APIs (that do not require jail breaking) for some of these, and for other aspects, you will need a jailbroken phone.

Comment: I want to run my app in background, be able to launch and stop other apps, be able to run timer (and wake up by timer from background), turn on and off the device, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its possible without actually jailbreaking the physical device. Check out the second answer to this question for some more information. [iOS app without developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak?rq=1)