# iOS developer account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to develop an application on iPhone but i don`t have the 100$ fee to pay to apple.
Is it necessary to have a developer paid account just for developing and deploying to device for test?

I already develop on Android and there i do not need to register and pay the fee just for developing.

Comment: You can get all the developer tools for free, and you can test on the simulator, but to test on a real (non-jailbroken) device (which is very important, and for some functions even absolutely necessary), you need to cough up the money.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop and test on simulator without having paid Apple Developer Account. But if you want to run on device for testing you must register for a $99 paid Apple Developer account as you have to create certificate and provisioning profile for deploying on device.

Comment: But is the simulator good enough to "simulate" the real device ?Would i have any problems when deploying it to device , if the app runs ok on simulator?

Comment: Good enough to get you started, not good enough for a release. And some features are not available on the simulator at all.

Comment: Yes agreed with @Thilo. You must test app on real device before release. As there are some features which aren't available on simulator. Memory testing can't be done completely without a real device. Sometimes you find crashes on device which never occur on simulator!!

Comment: Another area is interaction with other apps (including some of the built-ins). You cannot get those on the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the tools for free. Yet, you need a mac to develop for iphone. To get used to the environment, learn and use it you can do all that in a simulator. But If you need to test in a real device or submit your app you need to have the paid apple developer account. 
Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak?lq=1)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you also need a Mac (which is probably the next question to come up)