# provisioning portal, paid membership?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

I need to build an app on my iPhone, and need to download a profile, do I absolutely have to pay the 99$ membership? even if I am not ready to deploy to the app store?

So I am still fiddling with the app, not ready for production, I still have to pay the 99$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is required that you have a paid membership to the iOS Developer Program (Any type) to run an application on your device, or to submit to the App Store.

See [Apple's Developer Program page](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/%20%22Apple%27s%20Developer%20Program%20Page) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Apple will not give out provisioning profiles to anyone who isn't registered with the Apple Developer program. In fact, the process to create/retrieve a provisioning profile is done through Apple's online Developer program website.

EDIT:

This is a long-shot for sure, but if you were looking to simply get the app onto your device, you theoretically ask a friend or colleague who is registered with the program to add your XCode project to their computer, add a provisioning profile for your device, and then download the app to your device. But again, that would require for at least someone to have paid for the Apple Developer Program.