# test apps on ipad mini

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I just jail broken my ipad mini. Now I want to test my apps on my device but I cannot see any option in xcode where I can test it on my device. How can I test my apps on my ipad mini?

Comment: Copy over the app bundle to /Applications on your device and respring.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Comment: @H2CO3 how can I get to /Applications directory?

Comment: That answer is for old ipad devices. My question is about ipad mini with latest version of ios.

Comment: check this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0JS0D2tXGY