# How do i test my app in my iPod without Apple developer subscription

Tags: ios, xcode

I already changed the `Code Signing Identity` into  `Don't code sign` but it still won't run on my device it gives me the error

`No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.`

What else should i do to make it work? please help.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your iOS version deployment target, if your iPod iOS version is less than the one you are supporting it would not work.

Example: if your iPod is with iOS 4.3 and you are deploying for 5.0 will not work.

Comment: i checked it, the device's OS is 6.1 it's not compatible with xcode 4.5.2, im upgrading to 4.6 now. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot run an app on a device (iPod, iPhone or iPad) without signing the app and having it part of a provisioning profile.  That can only happen if you have a paid development account with Apple.  You can run in the simulator all you want, but to deploy on a device requires a developer account.  The only alternative is via jailbreak, but that still won't help you if your intention is to publish to the Apple App Store at some point.

See [THIS SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak) post for more info.  You really ought to do a little searching first :)

Comment: All the comments I read (other than the one by the answer user) said that the device needed to be jailbroken to work.  If you think you can make this work using that answer, jump all over it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to run and test an app on a device without a paid iOS developer license. I tried to figure out a way to test on my device without paying, but it turns out that buying the license was worth it anyway. If your going to be testing an app that needs testing on a device, odds are that buying the license will be worthwhile.