# Can I use my iPad to test my application instead of only the iOS simulator bundled with XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

Is this possible or do I have to create a prepaid account for $99?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a prepaid account indeed to deploy anything on an apple device. Otherwise it would mean anybody could hack a non-accepted application to people's devices, which would make iPhones and iPads pretty vulnerable to… well basically anything so I guess the answer is common sense.