# Running app on iOS device without certificate from Apple

Tags: objective-c, xcode, certificate, ios-simulator, iphone-developer-program

How can I run my app on physical iOS device without apple developer programm? I read some tutorials but there are only for jailbroken devices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to run apps on an iDevice without an official Apple certificate, because you have to sign the app.
A solution is, to jailbreak your phone and sign it yourself (you already found the tutorials), so you just need AppSync to run them.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I got the certificate on my phone with my Apple Id, and I haven't actually paid for it yet, and I run it every day on my phone. I'm pretty sure you can get the certificate without having to pay for it, you just have limited options in app capabilities(No access to platforms like GameCenter without paying).