# Test for the IPhone Application

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I am working on iPhone application.i want to check the application in between the development period? Is there any way by which i can check my application on IPhone device
with out registering and paying 99$ to Apple?
Please suggest me if there is any way available for that??

Comment: If you want to test your app on a device you will need to get a paid developers account. This is the only way you can test apps without a cumbersome jailbreak loading mechanisme. With a paid account you can easily debug your app with Xcode without any special setup.

Comment: Sir,i want to know whether i have to pay 99$ or without paying i can check the application on IPhone device or not?

Comment: No you can not check your app on your iPhone without paying the 99$. Just as my previous comment stated, you need a paid developers account!

Comment: See also: [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but unless you have a jailbroken device you will not be able to test your application on an iDevice without purchasing the [$99 Apple developer account.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/)

Also have a read of the [Apple App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) it will help give a good understanding of how to do it the official way without a jailbroken device.

Just as a reference for if you decide to use a jailbroken device here is also a [guide](https://www.alexwhittemore.com/developing-jailbroken-iphone-iphone-312/) but unfortunately to do it the official way you are require to purchase the $99 Apple Developer account.