# Deploy iOS app with Provisioning Profile that lasts longer than 1 year

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have built a couple of iOS apps for clients which are in regular use; however, each year the provisioning profile runs out and I have to redeploy them (I deploy them direct, not through the app store, and they are all using iOS 6).

Is there any way to deploy iOS apps direct to device without the provisioning profile running out on a yearly basis?

NB. I do have developer membership and am not asking if it's possible to deploy without developer membership.

Comment: I dont understand why you are taking responsibility for maintaining apps on app store. Get clients to pay for the account.

Comment: @2-Stroker I'm not maintaining apps on the app store. I'm deploying them direct to their devices - They paid me a one off fee for developing them and I am charging them to renew the profile each year. However, it's something I don't really want to have to do. I was hoping it might be possible to deploy to the device (whilst having developer membership) an 'everlasting' provisioning profile or some way to deploy that would mean the profile didn't expire a year later.

Comment: @jx by default its set to expire in an year unlike droid. This cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. That is the whole reason for certificates and provisioning profiles. So apps don't get distributed without being signed by the maker.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but is there no way to distribute it so that the profile doesn't need renewing every year?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not...see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Comment: Thanks, Michal, I'd seen that and severel other similar questions. The slight difference is I am registered with the developer network. I was hoping while being registered I could deploy to the device an 'evergreen' profile or something similar so it didn't need renewing each year.

Comment: I feel your pain and I wish it would be possible. But from the other side - it really is the only way how to keep at least some part of the garbage/spam-like apps off the earth...