# Connecting iPhone device to Xcode project

Tags: iphone, testing, device

So i created the free version of the iPhone app development account today. I'll make the official one later when i'll be ready to distribute app. I received the impression that with the free developer account i can test my app on my actual device instead of always using Xcode's simulator. I'm looking around the iOS dev account and i can't seem to find anywhere that it'd allow me to connect my iPhone to my Xcode project. How do i connect my iPhone to my Xcode project to test my app on a real device?

I'm using Xcode 6.1 if that makes a difference.

Comment: You cannot do it without having $99 account. Not possible. At least legally.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create apple Developer Account if you don't have one.
2. Register you device in developer portal if you haven't done that before.
3. Register an App Bundle ID by going to Certificates, identifiers and profiles if you haven't done that.
4. Create your developer certificate if you haven't done that before.
5. Create development provisioning profile with you device and certificate.
6. Download and install the certificate in xcode.
7. Download and install the created profile in xcode.
8. Select your profile and certificate under your xcode project build settings -> "Code Signing"

Comment: The only way i can connect an actual device to Xcode and test it is if i create the $99 a year developer program account that distributes the apps?

Comment: Well there are other ways but this is the only offical legal ways check this for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Answer (score 0):

The only and official way to test your application on a real device is to subscribe to a $99/year Apple developper account.