# Testing IOS apps on ios devices made using IONIC and angularJS

Tags: ios, angularjs, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I am making an app made using IONIC which I just want to test on my IOS device, not publish it to the app store.
Do I still need an Apple developer account ( by paying $99 ) or is MAC with XCODE and IONIC installed enough?

I just want to test it on my device, not publish it to the app store.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

I tried this today. Using XCODE 7 beta 2. Tested my project made using IONIC  with only APPLIE ID, NOT APPLE DEVELOPER ACCOUNT, and its working.

All you have to do is( for making IONIC projects and installing them on Physical devices without APPLE DEVELOPER ID)

1. Install XCODE version 7 (currently beta 2)
2. Install Node JS (update path)
3. Install Cordova
4. make an ionic project ( IONIC start yourproject blank)

IOS platform is added by default.

5. go to platforms/ios folder
6. there will be a yourproject.xcode file - open it
7. Connect your device to the MAC
8. Run your project - if you get any error, XCODE gives the option of fix issue, click on that and your app will be installed on the physical device

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can confirm this, as I had to do it myself too. You have to buy an Apple developer license in order to test the app **on your phone**. I know this sounds crazy as you're not actually putting it to the store, just 'testing', but hey that's Apple ;).

However, if you would only like to run it in an Xcode **emulator**, you don't have to.

**edit:** Here is the official document confirming this: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-CODE_SIGNING_IN_A_NUTSHELL-IPHONE_CERTIFICATES

And besides, here's a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak) asking a similar thing and the reply is the same.

Comment: In the second answer(very recent) to the question you have pointed at says it is possible, though not confirmed for IONIC, so is there any way of checking it for IONIC ?

Comment: Well, in that case test the second option and see for yourself. On another note, if you're serious about making an app, why not buy the license, which in end you'll still have to, in order to be able to publish to Apple store?

Comment: then i will check it and let you know, and sorry i can't accept your answer until i am sure its not possible using the new method.

Comment: Ok, when you test let me know. You are testing this on a Mac, right?

Comment: yes i'm testing it on a MAC. are there any other requirements , like code signing, or some certificates in the current method being used ?

Comment: All this Xcode does for you, but only once you have the developers account, because you have to sign in before actually creating certificates and signing and all other stuff that's needed. Steps outlined here in the official docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Comment: apple is hellish to work with. If you don't have to make a apple version don't

Comment: @JessPatton: actually, while it's true that they have really strict guidelines I found it actually very straightforward to get my first app to the app store (using Ionic). Truth be told I got it in Android play store in 3 hours and for the App Store I had to wait for 8 days :O

Comment: recently they rejected one of our apps due to the fact that our app contained a company blog article saying we were also releasing a android version. Because the there was a word referencing android in our app they rejected it. So now we have to content filter all blog articles for our app to make sure we never reference another mobile platform or we will get rejected again.

Comment: OK, in that case, I'll admit, a bit sneaky from their side :(.