# Can I test my Ionic App on my iOS device without Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I tested my app on Android and Windows Phone 8.1 without any problem, and I want to test it on iOS.

I have never tested my App on it.

Before buying a Developer Program, I want to test my App first.
Is it possible to test my Ionic / Cordova App without having (paying 99$) Developer Program ?

If so how can I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing IOS apps on ios devices made using IONIC and angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134825/testing-ios-apps-on-ios-devices-made-using-ionic-and-angularjs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of XCode 7 it is possible to do this by getting a free Developers account, you should automatically get such an account when you try to deploy an app on a device in XCode.

There are however some limitations to such an account, you can compare all the memberships [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/). A much more detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak).

Answer (score 2):

You could use Ionic View. I works great as long as you don't need to access non core plugins...

http://view.ionic.io/