# Build iOS app without apple developer ID

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I want to develop and publish (not in app store) an app for iOS. use some tool like (http://diawi.com)

Is there any way to do that without Apple developer account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Comment: You cant distribute in an official way without the account, jailbreak might be an option but your targets is reduced a lot

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do that without Apple developer account?

If you're willing to jail-break your phone and require that all your users also jail-break, there are ways to distribute without going through the app store. You might want to read about [Cydia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cydia).

However, if you want to distribute your app to most iPhone or iPad owners, you'll need to distribute through the app store. If you want to distribute only within your organization, you can use enterprise distribution instead. Neither of these methods are available without a developer account.