# Unable to deploy iOS app to iPhone with Xcode 7

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode7

I recently downloaded the Xcode 7 Beta in hopes of using the new feature that allows you to test apps on your phone without paying their developer fee. I followed the steps in the answer to this question

[Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

However, I am unable to choose my device in the scheme because it is under ineligible devices. When I click 'Fix Issue', I get the error "Unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device, enable it for development, and add it to the Member Center using the Organizer." However, I cannot do any of this because I do not have a paid Apple developer account. How can I get Xcode to create a free provisioning profile and allow my phone to be used for testing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To deploy an app to a device, it has to be registered in the member center. Since this functionality isn't available until iOS 9 is released, you won't be able to run it until then.

Xcode 7 doesn't change anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

Join the developer forums or just log in to the developer centre with your Apple ID and then things will start to work as you will have joined the free tier of the developer program https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/ and Xcode 7 will show your apple ID as having free ios and mac development under accounts in the Xcode preferences section.

I've had no problems testing on an iPhone 6 and old iPad 3 both with iOS 8.whatever :)

Xcode 7 automatically registers your device, installs two development certificates in your keychain (Mac & iOS) and provides provisioning profile management ... thats kind of the whole point :)