# Install app on iOS device (iPhone / iPad) or create .ipa from Xcode without code signing and developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, iphone-developer-program, code-signing-entitlements

I am new to iOS development and self learning.  I have created couple of  apps and already tested in iOS simulator.   These apps runs perfectly fine without any issues and warnings pre or post build.

I wanted to run apps on my iPhone for realtime testing. But cannot extract .ipa package from Xcode as i did not subscribe to developer's account yet (will do later). Tried few tweaks and followed below steps :-

1. Updated **SDKsettings.plist and set CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED, ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED to value NO**.(*read at tech blog*)
2. Created archive and export method as : **"Save for Ad Hoc Deployment"**
3. Further steps asked for developers account again. So tried to fetch **.app /.ipa** from xcarchive in two ways :

   a). Run command line:
   `xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath /Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/..\app.xcarchive/ -exportPath /Users/../Desktop/app.ipa`

   b). Copied .app file underneath the above xcarchive package. Dargged and dropped to iTunes "MyApps"
4. Within iTunes, i noticed that app size grew from 2.2 MB to 8.4 MB.
5. Connected iPhone using USB and performed install then clicked sync/apply. App gets installed on device but iTunes shows "installing"
6. Disconnected USB, installed App has no icon image. When touched to open the app, it starts installing and never opens up.

***Please help suggest pointers so that i can test my app without developer's account***.

Comment: Xcode 7 should allow this now. See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4952845/171206

Comment: Thanks, It worked after upgrading to Xcode 7 beta 3. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to download the beta version of XCode 7, so you can do this in an "official" way. Or you can wait until XCode 7 is released to the public.

When I was starting at development and I didnt have an Apple Developer Membership I used [JailCoder](http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/). With this tool you can fake sign your apps and install it into your device wothout a membership, and most important, DEBUG your apps. *You need a jailbroken device*

Comment: Thanks, It worked after upgrading to Xcode 7 beta 3. I always wanted to do it officially only without playing around with app but had to test my app anyhow.