# iOS App's on Device with xCode6.4 and xCode7 beta

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, xcode6.4

i want add a Comment to these Answer,[Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak) but i don't have 50 comments :(
I want to know if is possible that I install xCode7 beta, than go back to xCode6.4 and start from xCode6.4 my App on my device? I have problems with the convert from my projects from xCode6.4 in xCode7. I hope someone can help me. I can start the Apps from xCode7 on my device without problems :) but i need the code from xCode6.4...

Please Help me...

Greetz

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this touches on legal issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode is only an IDE you use. In general, an IDE could switch freely. 
BUT with IOS development you always work against a Base SDK that defines the abilities of the apple frameworks.

Now Xcode 7 comes with IOS SDK 9
Xcode 6 comes with IOS SDK 8

---

So Switching between Versions of Xcode also switches the base sdk (unless otherwise configured)

---

--> your app may behave differently with different base sdks. If that is acceptable though OR you don't see any change THEN switching is no issue

I switch all the time :)

### EDIT: just saw the swift 2 tag. That is not supported in Xcode 6 so you can't switch

Comment: The app i develop is for iOS8.4 than i can work in xcode 7 and xcode6.4 :) But can i switch to xcode 6.4 and run my app on device? Without develop programs. In xCode7 u don't need that in xCode 6.4 u need the develop Programm...

Comment: then you can't run it on device.. not with xcode6 ... not without developer program

Comment: if you have it all setup, it doesn't matter which xcode

Comment: Look at the  post from Mister Mister: He write:  
Just FYI: I installed Xcode 7 and tried running on my phone but I couldn't get all the build dependencies right, so I switched back to Xcode 6 and finally was able to run on my own device! Xcode 7 must add some license to your account that Xcode 6 recognizes :) –  Mister Mister Jul 19 at 4:27 also i can run it or ?

Comment: you aren't seriously asking plainly about doing unalloyed stuff.. I haven't voted to close yet but now you are plainly abusing SO