# Xcode 7 Error "no code signing identities found" When Build Using Free Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently i'm trying to sideload xcode 7 app to my iphone.
But I always got this error:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0B4cWQXc78eSUFLakJkZ1N1THc/view

When i click that 'Fix issue' button I got popup like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0B4cWQXc78eaHhnendJVUVkWVU/view

This is a new fresh project and never signed on another mac, so I dont have that "developer certificate" and i'm using Free Provisioning Profile. 
I click that reset button but that popup always come again.
I hope someone can help me to solve this problem -_-
Sorry for my English and my reputation is 1 so I can't post an image.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After Stackoverflowing... for hours, clean rebuild derived data ecc... I found the solution "Moving to trash" the provisioning profile I already have and downloading again, but first I repeat DELETE IT!

[image: How to delete Provisioning Profile]

Comment: This really helped me. I had created the provisioning profile with a different distribution certificate and when I reinstalled the provisioning profile this old one was still being used.

Answer (score 3):

import your developer certificate and add it into keychain  check  [Exporting and Importing Certificates and Profiles help](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW15)  and [apples troubleshooting page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html)

apple documentaion says

**If the certificate already exists in Member Center, a “Your account already has a valid certificate” dialog appears. Typically, this happens when you move from one Mac to another. If possible, export your certificates as a developer profile file on the other Mac, and then import them on your new Mac, as described in Exporting and Importing Certificates and Profiles. If you don’t have a backup of your developer profile, click the “Revoke and Request” button when the “Your account already has a valid certificate” dialog appears.**

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but this is a new fresh project and never signed on another mac, so i dont have that "developer certificate" and i'm using Free Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Hi  can you please check In Xcode  your Apple ID is added to Accounts preferences, please check the answer for this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Answer (score 0):

This can be happened due to several reasons and can be solved by one of the below solution:

1. Try Quiting Xcode and Reopen it.
2. Install Provisioning profile again in Xcode.
3. Download iOS Development/Distribution certificates from your developer account and install it in keychain.
4. Open Xcode Preference and Signin to your developer account again.

Hope any of these solution may work!!