# How to access apple signing certificates?

Tags: ios, cordova, cross-platform, phonegap-build

This is Minton. I've recently discovered a software known as "Adobe PhoneGap". It involves using HTML CSS and Javascript to write apps.

Everything is going fine, but when I want to put my alpha test onto my iphone for testing, it tells me that I need a valid signing certificate and provisioning profile to put apps onto my phone.

For iphone apps I have been using XCode and thus the profiles are linked to my apple ID (I'm using the free one just to put alpha tests onto my device), but how do I access my certificate files (if any) in PhoneGap?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your mobile App on your iPhone you have two options :

**Build the app directly to your phone via terminal command**

```
cordova run ios --device
```

**Add your UDID to your provisioning profile**

you have to get your iPhone UDID which you can get it from you iTunes while connecting the iPhone to it 
then add this unique number to  `Devices` tab on your Apple developer account 
and then add this device to your provisioning profile you are using with this APP

After finish all development on the app you can upload it via application loader which come with XCode to the app store where you can install it to any iPhone compatible with your supported version of iOS

Comment: Would this work for a free apple ID? Apple has a function in XCode that allows you to put alpha build apps onto your iphone for free, without having to buy a developer membership. Just wondering. Thanks!

Comment: @MintonLee please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4952845/4183947