# Get app file ios xcode 7/8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode8

I want to send an app I wrote to a friend but I can't find answers on how to extract the .app file in XCode 7 or 8. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: also is there a way to reduce the file size without deleting major components of the .app file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the app is able to run. Choose the "Archive" option from the "Product" menu in xcode. When it's done, open the Organizer window and click the "Archive" tab. Click the build you want (should be the top one) and then click the "Export" button on the right side. You will probably want Ad Hoc deployment or Development Deployment. This will export an IPA file to your hard drive. You can mail it to your friend who can load it with iTunes.

It's easier if you have a dev account, you can register other test devices.  Look here for details when you have no dev account;

[Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Comment: I don't have a developer's account, but the instructions you gave me only worked for downloading onto a personal device. My friend doesn't live near me, so how would I do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do it without either an account or jailbreaking the target device.

Answer (score 2):

**For Xcode 8.x**

1. Click on Window tab -> Organizer
2. Right click the archive you need to get the .app file from (do not right click on the Name text as that will edit the text)
3. Show in Finder
4. Right click on the .xcarchive file that is selected -> Show Package Contents -> Products -> Applications
5. There's your file

You can hit command+i to make sure it's a .app file if the extension is hidden!