# Revoking the Provisioning profile created by Xcode 8 GM

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, xcode8

I had created a provisioning profile for the app using Xcode(I have not joined developer program but I have an apple account).Now I want to revoke the provisioning profile (not just deleting it). But I'm not finding any provision to revoke the account in Xcode as well as Member center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created the provisioning profile using user account i.e. you don't have an apple developer account, then you have to run the app using new bundle ID so that your old Id gets revoked. Try chaing your bundle ID 3-4 times so that your old ID gets revoked. If you have used developer account you can visit developer site and manually revoke it.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 8, you can now set Xcode to automatically manage provisioning profiles, by checking the box in General Tab, this should fix any provisioning profile issues you may be having.

[image]

Comment: This will create a new provisioning profile, but I want to revoke an existing provisions profile

Comment: I don't understand, you don't revoke provisioning profiles, you can revoke certificates, with provisioning profiles you delete them from the developer account where they were created, if you want to sign your app without a provisioning profile, you can specify this in Xcode.

Comment: I don't have any developer account (i.e. I didn't enrol myself to developer program). As I have an apple account I logged in  through it and created a provisioning profile in Xcode (refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)  now I want to revoke it.

Comment: You can navigate to: /Users/[userName]/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ and delete any provisioning profiles in this folder.

Comment: This deletes the profile from Xcode but I want to revoke the profile so that I can create new profile with the same bundle ID.

Comment: @ShaileshChandavar were you able to solve this issue??

Comment: @HardikAmal Yes I have got a solution. I will provide it .