# How can get the ipa file extension ionic on windows

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, apk, ipa

I've just finished developing my application with ionic. I'm working on windows and run :

```
ionic run android
```

I managed to get the apk file, but when I tried to get the ios vesion (.ipa) it gave an error:

> You cannot run iOS unless you are on Mac OSX.

How can I get the ipa version from windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't build the .ipa package  in your Windows machine because you'll need XCode for that.

You can use this: https://web.archive.org/web/20150303180446/http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac

but still you need a machine with ios installed, this is just about certificate generation. Also the final version of your app, must be uploaded with XCode.

So a possible solution is to install a macOS  virtual machine on windows base pc.

Also you can get virtual mac machine. Have a look at these:

http://www.macincloud.com

http://www.macminivault.com

Comment: thank you Antonis for this answer...i have one more question...if i installed MacOs virtual machine i will have to do all the stuff that i did on windows i mean ..install cordova....install IDE and then import the projet??

Comment: and to generate the certificate is free??

Comment: Yes you have to install all of these. To give you an example, to build my app in ios i found a Mac pc. There i installed cordova, ionic ect and after that my project was able to run of course. The thing that i didn't know is that the packages and libraries that i had installed in android, are found automatically and i didn't had to install again. Something that was good

Comment: Yes but keep in mind that you will need xcode 7 for that. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak, and this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206123/xcode-7-develop-for-ios-without-developer-account

Comment: thank you very match Antonis...and what about the certificate why we use it ? and its free to create one??

Comment: Please take a look here: http://blog.ionic.io/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/. These are the steps for build and run the app. The certificates will need when you want to publich your app in your market. But with these you will able to test your app in emulator. If you need to test in an actual device you will need a mac phone of course. As an advice i suggest to install the latest version of macOS in your virtual machine. I had problem with oldest versions with the xcode.Good luck! ;)