# Xcode 6.2–Cannot create free provisioning profile: "XXX" is not on any development teams

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, mobile-development

I'm trying to test my app on an iOS device using Xcode, however, when I go to create a personal team, this happens:

[image: Error]

Xcode says I'm not on any development teams, even though it's supposed to automatically create one. I've already googled this problem, and already tried restarting both Xcode and the computer, removing the Apple ID, and adding it back in again, updating Xcode, even reinstalling it, but to no avail.

Running Xcode 6.2 on an OSX 10.9.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need Apple developer account for testing on devices. Do you have it?

Comment: Can't you test without one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Comment: As I know, it's Xcode 7 feature, but you can try as in this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak#comment50959463_4952845

Comment: @Cplusplusplus - you can't. What you linked says you don't need to join the developer program (i.e. don't need to pay), but you still need a free Apple Developer account. Also, as AndrewVergunov said, this was enabled with Xcode 7. On the other hand - any reason you are not using the latest Xcode?

Comment: My mac doesn't support the latest Xcode

Comment: @AndrewVergunov Okay, I'll try it on a different computer as my Mac doesn't support Xcode 7