# How can I run my iOS application?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I made a webview app on xcode. 
How can I run the application on my own device but I do not have my developer  account.

How can I do?

Comment: With a free Developers account you can run the app in iOS devices. Without any developers account you can't.

Comment: The answer lies here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak