# Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID in xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode

I just installed Xcode. Version is 9.0

I registered myself (personal team) as a team.

when i am run code then :

Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID com.xyz.abc

Thank you!

Comment: check your certificates with your developer account else check automatic option to manage certificates

Comment: i have used non paid account and i have tried that also

Comment: may be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Comment: i have face this error when i  used simulator. i am not using device

Comment: To running in simulator probably you dont need any accounts & certificates.set it to none

Comment: ya i know sir but i have face in xcode beta 9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147027/discussion-between-nishant-gupta-and-ds-dharma).

Comment: I am also getting the same issue with xcode 9 beta version. Do anyone have answer please post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, because I unzip and install Xcode on another laptop and then copy application to my own laptop!
Try download and install it again and avoid copy/paste.Just unzip it in your laptop.