# IOS application, ID bundle errors on XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I created an application with the Ionic Framework that allows me to make hybrid applications.
When I open my project on XCode, I have errors from XCode that I can not solve.

My errors are:

> "Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the target's
> entities file"
>
> "Provisioning profile ios team provisioning profile * doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement "
>
> "Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3' "

I think the ID bundle has a mistake, however, I do not understand how to solve it.
How do I create a correct ID bundle without going through the project creation box since mine is already creating basic? (My ID bundle was generated by the global application's in the config.xml file)

Is it necessary to have a paid developer account to be able to create one? Or can I test my app simply on my phone?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

These errors you are getting because of the no **Provisioning profile** & **Developer Certificate**. 
To Brief of what is provisioning profile & Developer certificates are, These are security certificates providing by Apple to make sure that the iOS application is built by identified developer.

> If you see there is a check mark: "Automatically manage signing" on.
>   Because of that, it's trying to create provisioning profiles and
>   certificates automatically without any proper apple membership
>   account. That results in an error.

To run on a device, you don't need to have paid account. Any Apple ID will work. You need to have at least normal Apple ID and have to put any random bundle identifier there to run on your iPhone. (You can follow this link to [How to run on iPhone without certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak))

**Answering another question of yours:** Yes, it's required to have Apple paid account to create a Bundle identifier. Even if you test it now on iPhone using above trick, to distribute in future to AppStore you need one.