# Can I test my Codename One app on my iOS device for free?

Tags: ios, codenameone

I have written a simple to-do list app in Codename One, and so far I have used the simulator to test it. I want to see how it looks on a real device (iPhone 5s or 8 Plus), but I don't want to purchase the Apple Developer membership. I really don't want to pay $99/year (I'm a beginner).

I know I can get the app on my device by jailbreaking it, but is that the only way?

So basically my question is, is there any method of installing my **Codename One app** on my iOS device (without paying for the membership or jailbreaking it)?

Clarification: I need to know how to test *Codename One* apps on my device. This is not the usual concern about how to test iOS apps on a device without membership or jailbreaking. I understand how to do this if I am coding in Swift.

[This video from Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html) shows how I can generate native projects. This alone would be sufficient, but building the iOS app requires a certificate, which requires an Apple Developer membership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a certificate from Apple to test on a device without using xcode and we can't realistically provide a way around it.

Getting a certificate for free from Apple is a different thing. Educational institutes usually have access to an educational apple developer account that allows you to do just that for free so if you are a student or know a student you can get access to one of those and use it to test your app on your device for free.

Comment: Thanks Shai! I don't belong to a university or know someone who does, though. Can you think of any other ways to get such an account?

Comment: Just a friend or something like that but that becomes tricky as you might have issues using the certificate wizard as it's a bit aggressive with revoking certificates.

Answer (score -1):

Since Xcode7 you can simply build on your device with Xcode, if you don't use any restricted capabilities. That said you would need to run your cross compiled code from `Codename One` in Xcode, to be able to run it on a device without a membership. (Not sure if it is possible to retrieve the cross compiled code.)

More context on building on device using Xcode:
[Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak/4952845#4952845)

Comment: While this answer is correct you clearly know that the question is duplicate. So vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.