# P12 certificate for free?

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate

This is my first time building an iOS app :)  I've created my app with phonegapp and I want to view my app on an iOS device. I was able to build the APK for Android with no problem; but after reading the documentation on iOS build I am a little confused.  I understand that I need to enroll myself on the Apple Developer Program, and for me to do so, there is a cost os US$99.

I just want to be able to view my app on my iPhone. Is there a free and simpler way to get around this? BTW, I'm using Windows OS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Comment: You can sign up to the Apple developer program for free, this should allow you to run the app on your own device, but not submit it to the App Store.

Comment: I've signed up for free, but to enroll I need to pay US$99 which I don't want to because I just want to view my app, not sell it.

Answer (score 0):

For a few years now, it has indeen been possible. All you now need is XCode 7 or higher and a (free) [AppleID](https://appleid.apple.com).

Please refer to the [XCode Manual](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev60b6fbbc7):

- **Step 1:** Add your Apple ID to Accounts preferences

  > To identify you and download information about your teams, add your
  >   Apple ID account to Accounts preferences. Xcode uses the Apple ID
  >   credentials to download information about all the teams you belong to.
- **Step 2:** Assign the targets in your project to a team

  > Assign each target in your project to a team. Xcode will store the
  >   signing assets-certificates, identifiers, and provisioning profiles - in
  >   the associated team account. If you enroll as an organization, your
  >   program role determines what tasks you can perform in Xcode. If you
  >   enroll as an individual, you are the Team Agent for a one-person team.
  >   If you are not a member of the Apple Developer Program, Xcode creates
  >   a personal team for you.
- **Step 3:** Add capabilities to your app

  > In the Capabilities pane, enable the app services you want to use.
  >   Xcode configures your project and updates your signing assets
  >   accordingly. If needed, Xcode enables the app service for the
  >   associated App ID and regenerates provisioning profiles it manages. To
  >   fully enable some app services, you may need to sign in to your
  >   developer account or App Store Connect.

After folowing these instructions you should be able to run your app on your iOS-device.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a solution if you have a Macbook :)  I was looking for a solution for Windows users.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, there is no way to archive this on a windows mashine. But of course, you could always try use some kind of virtualization like VMWare to run MacOS within Windows. But then I'm not an iOS developer and therefore I have no clue how well this will work.

Comment: Ok, thank you just the same.