# How do you get an app, created in Visual Studio 17 on windows, to my local iphone?

Tags: iphone, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, windows-10

How do you get an app created in Visual Studio 17 on windows to my local iphone?

I just downloaded and started using Visual Studio this week and did this tutorial 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/learn-app-building-basics-with-xamarin-forms-in-visual-studio

I want to learn the process of getting an app onto my local iphone. NOT the "app store"

I don't have a mac or access to a mac. 
My Computer has windows 10 and I have the iphone7

Comment: You need a mac to do this

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a few things. You have to enroll in the iOS developer program which costs about $100 a year. You're going to have to go through itunes and install the app that way. While your app will not be published, you have to do it this way. There no other way around it

Comment: Can you explain the process a little more in detail? how do I get the app from Visual Studio to ITunes and then how do I get it from iTunes to my iphone?

Comment: here is a good article that should get you started https://codewithchris.com/deploy-your-app-on-an-iphone/

Comment: You can deploy to your own device with a free developer account, but you still need a Mac

Comment: Jason are you referring to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak/4952845#4952845