# How do I run an app on a device without an Apple developer account

Tags: ios, xcode

I've found several sites with information on how this can be done, but none that seems to apply to Xcode 10.1 or iOS 12.1. The ones I've tried don't seem to work.
I've tried this:

1. Create an empty swift project 'single view app'
2. Set the Signing Team to my Personal Team (Apple ID)
3. Set the active scheme to my connected (USB) iPhone 7 plus
4. Press the Play button

What I get is a 'Failed with exit code 1' and a horrendous log message.

My device turns up with a red frame in the active scheme dropdown list. What does that mean?

I'm running a MacBook Air with High Sierra.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, new on this. What's a free account? I though it cost $99.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Comment: @JorgenR a free account can be used to run apps on device no need for paid for this step

Comment: What is the log message?

Answer (score 1):

You need to only have a free account then add it to

> Xcode->Preferences->Accounts

after that select it in automatic signing process , then you'll get a trust message upon first run to fix go to

> Settings->General->Device Managament -> Your profile name -> Trust

then re run

Comment: What's a free account? Just an Apple ID? I added it to XCode Preferences->Accounts and it has the role 'User'.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but I can't find Settings->General->Device Management on my iPhone.

Comment: Did you actually go to developer.apple.com and enroll your Apple ID in the developer program?

Comment: I tried, but stopped when I had to pay the $99. Couldn't see any other option.

Comment: No, you don't have to pay the $99. As long as you agreed to the developer program free membership you can add the account in Xcode settings->Accounts. The fact that you can select your team as the signing account suggests that this is all ok.

Answer (score 1):

1. You just need to have apple developer account, which is free. If you don't have that create a using this link:- https://developer.apple.com
2. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts, login with your developer account, and download profiles.

[image]

3. Select your project, Go to general tab, select automatically manage signing and Team as your personal team.
4. Run your project, After successful build. you will get an error in Xcode stating your app is not from trustworthy source.
5. Now in your device, Go to Settings, search for "Device Managament", select Your profile name and Trust.
6. Run your app again.