# not able to add .ipa file in iphone device

Tags: xamarin

i have generated the .ipa file and trying to add in any iphone device but its not adding.

1. the error is showing like:- couldnot install(in xcode).
2. i tried with apple configurator 2:- in this scenario app is installing a bit just assume 
   75% and after that the app icon is getting grayed out and clicking on that app is giving 
   popup as :- could not install please try later.
3. somewhere i saw that you have to allow from your device to trust this app, location is like :- settings > general > profile&management > you will find your profile here for new app installing.i didn't get any profile there.

FYI

i am using free developer account and created the xamarin app from windows and building it through mac, the xcode version is 9.4 beta and i also tried to override with xcode version 11.3.
i am not getting whether i am missing something or messed up with xcode versioning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53261344/8970176

Answer (score 0):

> i am using free developer account and created the xamarin app from windows and building it through mac...

If using a free apple developer account , you can not install a `.ipa` file to iOS Device .This is limited by Apple.

About [IPA Support in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows) , you will see there are two uses as follow :

- **Ad Hoc Testing** — An iOS application can be deployed to up to 100 users (identified by specific iOS device UUIDs) for Alpha and Beta testing purposes. See our Provisioning an iOS Device for Development documentation for detailed information on adding test iOS devices to your Apple developer account, and the Ad-Hoc guide, for more information on how to distribute in this way.
- **In House / Enterprise Deployment** — An iOS application can be deployed internally, within a company, which requires membership of Apple's Developer Enterprise program. More information on In House Distribution is detailed in the In House Distribution guide.

In either case, an IPA package (a special type of zip file) must be created and digitally signed with the correct **Distribution Provisioning Profile**.

If using a free provisioning , there is a [Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows#limitations) as follow :

- Access to iTunes Connect is limited and therefore services such as publishing to the App Store and TestFlight are unavailable to developers provisioning their applications freely. An Apple Developer Account (Enterprise or Personal) is required to distribute via Ad Hoc and In-House means.

**Therefore** , if need to add `.ipa` file in iphone device , you should use a paid Apple Developer Program account.