# Xcode Team is not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program

Tags: xcode

I'm developing my personal mobile application.
I've used react native to build the application, and I'm now trying to bring my application on my iPhone X, using Xcode, however, when I'm trying to deploy the application I've got the following error:

> Team [*My Team Name*] is not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program.

Is enrolling mandatory even for testing on personal devices?

Thanks!

What I did is listed below:

1. Created a Development certificate
2. Couldn't create a Distribution certificate ("Your account does not have permission to create iOS Distribution certificates")
3. Build the project correctly
4. Set signing of the project (both application and testing) to my Development certificate
5. Set scheme to my personal iPhone X
6. Click on "Distribute App"
7. Try on both, "Ad hoc" and "Development"

The only answer I've got is the error shown above.

Comment: Did you try changing "Team" in "Signing" in your target's settings to "None" ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I did, but it gives me an error: "Signing for "MyApp" requires a development team."

Comment: Try [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952845/1032372)
(Did you sign into your Apple ID?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks shim, I didn't have all those options since I'm using Xcode 10, however playing around with the signature settings I've made it out.
For whom other that will struggle with this issue, basically there's no point to archive the project to deploy on the Device.

The solution was just to select my device in the within the Schemas and just Run it on the device, that actually install the app on the mobile device.