# Is it possible to deploy xamarin.forms ios to iphone without apple developer accaunt?

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I want to test my xamarin.forms application on my Iphone 11 pro
witout Apple developer accaunt

I try this but it nor work

**create swift app with xcode and use same bundle identifier from my xamarin.forms.ios app but this no work after swift app deploy ,i cant run my xamarin application
that thrown an erorr he0004 resone image not found**

Comment: your title and the actual question you have asked seem to be completely unrelated

Comment: I tried to change it

Answer (score 0):

Apple has finally introduced a new feature in **Xcode 7** that allows you to deploy and run any number of apps on any of your devices, simply by logging in with your **Apple ID**. You will no longer need a paid Program membership to deploy apps on your own device.

You could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952845/10768653).

Answer (score 0):

You can do via 'Free provisioning for Xamarin.iOS apps', which will allow single application for single device with some limitations. You can find details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning).