# Is there a way to download custom apps on iOS (just like how apk works on android)?

Tags: ios, swift

So is there a way to make code for an iOS app, then download that iOS app without publishing it on the app store?

Edit: I'll ask a question that will help me find out how to download iOS app without publishing:
How do people test their apps before publishing them?

Comment: Not out of the box, on jailbroken iPhones that is possible, on "regular" ones it is not.

Comment: You can run your app on your own device using Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak.