# Add associated domain iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, dns

i need to add associated domain in my iOS App.
I configured the file apple-app-site-association and post it on server.
Now i should add the domain of the server in my app, but when i go to Signing and Capabilities i see this:

[image]

what's the problem?
I don't want to publish the app in App Store but only use for test develop

Comment: Like it said on the prompt, did you register any devices under your developer account?

Comment: No, i don't know how do it.

Comment: i don't want to pay

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Comment: You have to have a paid developer account for this feature

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna run the app in development mode and don't use paid developer account.

Try this one: [Defining a custom URL scheme for your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app)